# How to edit a ring-shaped image into a straight line?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, image-editing

I am looking for a way to make the image below straight - like in the line. To make it clear - it would be a tattoo template, which will be placed *around* my upper arm.

[image: logo]

Is there any solution of this, in Photoshop?

Comment: Cant be done easily. Redrawing it would be easier.

Comment: My solution is below, but @scott is correct. Take the image to your tattoo artist. They will do a better job by just redrawing it.

Comment: Hello Krystina, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. I took the liberty to edit it to clarify it a bit and make it easier to read. If I butchered it beyond your recognition, feel free to revert my edits. If you have any questions about Stack Exchange of this site in particular, have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) or the [help]. Keep contributing and good luck with the tattoo!

Comment: In passing – Do you want the bird head to be inverted relative to the other two? — I wonder how many people familiar with complex numbers are thinking “Just take the logarithm.”

Comment: If no one else is going to say it - look, I love TES as much as anyone but seriously consider whether you want to have the logo for a (rather mediocre) MMORPG on you for _life_.

Answer (score 27):

It won't be perfect but you could use a Polar Coordinates filter (*Filter → Distort → Polar Coordinates...*) set to "Polar to Rectangular" on the image:

[image]

The result will be "straight", but will be distorted so you'll at least need to adjust the height to compensate. This is after transforming the layer to 50% height:

[image]

With a further bit of correction using a mesh warp (*Edit → Transform → Warp*):

[image]

Comment: This is a much more efficient solution. (Plus after 15 years, I now know a use for Polar Coordinates.)

Comment: @GoofyMonkey indeed.... I can probably count the times I've used Polar Coordinates on one hand

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, but I couldn't get it to work! I guess I centered the image the wrong way. Good see that my first instinct was right!

Comment: @GoofyMonkey I actually use polar coordinates regularly, it's really awesome for making [mini planets](http://bit.do/miniplanet).

Answer (score 10):

This can be done. But not done very accurately. There will be some warping and distortion when you straighten it out. That said, here's what I would do.

1. Cut the piece into 3 separate pieces using your favorite selection method. I suggest the pen tool, but you don't really need to be that accurate.

[image: Selection]

2. Put each piece on it's own layer.
3. Then use the Puppet Warp Tool (Edit > Puppet Warp) to straighten each piece out. Add points along the curve and align the points and image into a straight(ish) line.

[image: Add Points]

4. If you need to, you can align the layers into one long line.

[image]